# How can I make an UEFI USB tools stick?

Tags: windows, uefi, operating-systems, iso-image, rufus

In the past I had an BIOS (MBR) USB tool stick with a few ISO tools on it, which could be used as an emergency tool stick.

But how can I make such a USB stick with more ISOs on it for UEFI (GPT)? I do know Rufus, but there I can only make ONE ISO bootable on the STICK. Is there a solution to make a multi-ISO UEFI boot stick with some tools on it?

Comment: This is off-topic and will be closed here. Ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered Also, don't use caps lock randomly for various words.

Comment: As @Destroy666 says, the Software Recommendations stack exchange is the sure for such a question. But even prior to that do a bit of your own research on it. Simply Googling "multi-ISO UEFI boot stic" brings up all the good solutions for this.

Comment: @YisroelTech thanks a lot

Comment: Clover Bootloader is what you want.

Comment: @Mastaxx thanks but the config is complicated. Do you know how it is done für UEFI PCs when I just have a few bootalbe ISOs.

Comment: I found Ventoy: https://github.com/ventoy